# Cannot Get Token from Uber API with Valid Access Key

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I've been trying for the past few days to integrate my app with uber, but for some reason during the oauth2 authentication I can't get uber to give me a valid token.  I can get an access code but when using curl, I can't seem to get an access token, no matter how I arrange my script.  Here's what I have:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['code']."<br>";
$token = curl_init();
$param = array(
    'client_secret' => 'MY_SECRET',
    'client_id' => 'MY_ID',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => "{$_GET['code']}"
    );
$postData = '';
foreach($param as $k => $v)
    {
       $postData .= $k . '='.urlencode($v).'&';
    }
$postData = rtrim($postData, '&');
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/token');
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$returned_token = curl_exec($token);
curl_close($token);
echo $returned_token;

?>
```

I've double checked my secret and id, both are correct.  I can see each time I'm going to get the access code it's something unique, I can see it echoed out on the authorization page I'm redirecting to, but no matter what I keep getting the response as:

```
{"error": "access_denied"}
```

Comment: Have none of the solutions worked for you? If they have, or if they seem best, you should mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because:

- You are not sending a redirect_uri parameter to the [GET https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize) endpoint and you also didn't set a redirect URI in [Uber Developers Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/) for the client application you are using in the API requests.

> Redirect URL
>   These URLs will be used during OAuth Authentication.
>   If no redirect URI is included with your request, the default URL will be
>   used.

- You are sending an invalid redirect URL (the base of the URI is not the same as the redirect URL set in Uber Developers Dashboard),
  as the documentation for the [GET https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize) says:

> redirect_uri (optional)
>   The URI we will redirect back to after an
>   authorization by the resource owner.
>   The base of the URI must match the redirect_uri used during the registration of your application.

Comment: I included the request_uri but can see only the authorization code and not the return token.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Make sure the `Content-Type` header is correct. Some services will expect that. (e.g. `Content-Type=x-www-form-urlencoded`)

Also, can yo share how you are requesting the `code`? (e.g. which `scope` are you using when sending the Authorization request, etc).

Comment: `curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type=x-www-form-urlencoded"));`  Like this?  Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this problem and it looks like I found the reason of it.

Try adding *redirect_uri* (the same as in app settings) to your request, so your params code should look like this:

```
$param = array(
'client_secret' => 'MY_SECRET',
'client_id' => 'MY_ID',
'redirect_uri' => 'MY_REDIRECT_URI',
'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
'code' => "{$_GET['code']}"
);
```

That helped me, but I hope Uber developers will make this error more specific

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me perfectly. My problem was that I had a difference between the Url Redirect on Dashboard app and The parameter that i send to the request. I fixed it and everything works fine

Comment: How does this add anything to the highest-ranked solution? And how is this not just a comment, rather than putting in a full answer?