# Uber Base Redirect Error

Tags: https, flask, uber-api

I currently have set up a developer account on uber and everything was fine running locally on my PC and http://localhost:7000/submit

I can log in and work with the API.  This is great for testing out endpoints.  However, my end goal is to use the endpoints on my mobile app.  So I went to the redirect URL and switched it to https://my_new_url:7000/submit

I'm using Flask for my server and am using SSL in the following manner:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=7000,ssl_context='adhoc')
```

However, when navigating to my base url I'm given the following error:

> ERROR
>
> THE BASE REDIRECT URI DOES NOT MATCH THE REQUESTED REDIRECT

The code for the base url looks as follows:

```
def get_redirect_uri(request):
    """Return OAuth redirect URI."""
    parsed_url = urlparse(request.url)
    if parsed_url.hostname == 'localhost':
        return 'http://{hostname}:{port}/submit'.format(
            hostname=parsed_url.hostname, port=parsed_url.port
        )
    return 'https://{hostname}/submit'.format(hostname=parsed_url.hostname)

@application.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def signup():
    params = {
        'response_type': 'code',
        'redirect_uri': get_redirect_uri(request),
        'scopes': ','.join(config.get('scopes')),
    }
    url = generate_oauth_service().get_authorize_url(**params)
    return redirect(url)
```

Do I have to have the application whitelisted before I can change the redirect URL or am I mis-configuring something?

Comment: Make sure your base url matches the one on the developer center you registered and specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the error response you received from the [/v1/oauth2/authorize](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize) endpoint, the problem is that the base of the URI you are sending must match the redirect URI used during the registration of your application in the Uber Developers Dashboard.

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638160/313113