# Unable to get access token-Uber API

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I am following the [authentication](https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/) document by Uber to perform OAuth 2.0 for my application. I am not able to access token (Step 3). It is continuously giving me "error:access denied". I am not able to figure out why is this issue coming. I provided access to my application and I am able to fetch the authorization code but when I am doing curl as per the documentation it is giving me access denied. Could someone please help me figure out this issue ? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the potentially the same issue, here's the cause and fix:

The API returns an 'access_denied' error when the 'redirect_uri' parameter of your POST request is either missing or invalid. Make sure it matches what you have set in the Uber application settings as your redirect URL.

Here is the same issue with a fix in PHP: [Cannot Get Token from Uber API with Valid Access Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429399/cannot-get-token-from-uber-api-with-valid-access-key)